# Issue with overlapping Rects using Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I am new to Pygame and I am in the experimentation phase.
What I have here is a simple display surface onto which I have rendered a few overlapping Rectangles with different colors with the same width and height (96 by 144) to simulate playing cards.

I have written some code in order to be able to highlight a card with the color Yellow when I click on it. If you run the code, you'll notice that when I click on the visible part of one of the cards, all the other cards that are behind it, as well as all of those that are overlapping it are being highlighted. I cannot figure out, what should I do to click the visible part of the card and only that card to highlight.

```
import pygame, sys

class Card(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, color):
        super().__init__()

        self.color = color
        self.is_highlight = False

    def show_card(self, x, y):
        self.rect = pygame.rect.Rect(x, y, 96, 144)
        pygame.draw.rect(display_surf, self.color, self.rect)


    def highlight_card(self):
        pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        if self.rect.collidepoint(pos):
            self.is_highlight = True
        else:
            self.is_highlight = False

    def update(self):
        if self.is_highlight:
            pygame.draw.rect(display_surf, 'Yellow', self.rect.inflate(5, 5), width=3, border_radius=5)

class Deck(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.card_deck = []

    def build_deck(self):
        self.card_deck.append(Card('Green'))
        self.card_deck.append(Card('Red'))
        self.card_deck.append(Card('Blue'))
        self.card_deck.append(Card('brown'))
        self.card_deck.append(Card('cadetblue'))
        self.card_deck.append(Card('cornsilk'))
        self.card_deck.append(Card('darkolivegreen'))
        self.card_deck.append(Card('darkorchid'))
        self.card_deck.append(Card('darksalmon'))
        return self.card_deck

pygame.init()

WINDOW_WIDTH = 1280
WINDOW_HEIGHT = 720

display_surf = pygame.display.set_mode((WINDOW_WIDTH,WINDOW_HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption('Simple Card Game')
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

card_deck = Deck().build_deck()


while True:

    display_surf.fill((0, 150,0))

    distance = 20
    for card in card_deck:
        card.show_card(distance, 20)
        distance += 20

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            for card in card_deck:
                card.highlight_card()

    for card in card_deck:
        card.update()

    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 0):

So I think I have solved my own question and wish to share the solution.

In the show_card method I have added a new scaled_rect which represents only the visible part of the colored card with a width of only 20, while I draw on the display surface the color using the original full sized rectangle:

```
def show_card(self, x, y):
    self.rect = pygame.rect.Rect(x, y, 96, 144)
    self.scaled_rect = pygame.rect.Rect((x, y), (20, 144))
    pygame.draw.rect(display_surf, self.color, self.rect)
```

In the highlight_card method I have made only the visible part of the color interactable with the mouse click, by using the new scaled_rect:

```
def highlight_card(self):
    pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    if self.scaled_rect.collidepoint(pos):
        self.is_highlight = True
    else:
        self.is_highlight = False
```

In the end, in the update method that draws the yellow colored highlight, I use the original full sized rectangle:

```
def update(self):
    if self.is_highlight:
        pygame.draw.rect(display_surf, 'Yellow', self.rect.inflate(5, 5), width=3, border_radius=5)
```